# How to make a div, header, container etc. cover the viewport

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to make a header that covers the entire viewport, no matter what size screen you use. That header will be horizontally divided into 3 sections that each fill 1/3 of the header.

- I have tried setting the height of the header to 100vh. Didn't work.
- I have tried setting the height of the header to 100%. Didn't work.
- I have tried setting the background-size of the header to cover. Also didn't work.

Could someone explain what the best approach would be to this.

Thanks

Comment: Get started with attempting something first, and then come back with a specific question if you encounter a problem.

Comment: it is weird. 100vh has to work in a modern browser. What is the value of `display` css-property of the <header> element in your styles?

Comment: Haven't set the value of the display yet. What should it be for the 100vh to work?

Comment: `display: block;` I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Flex for the win: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
<html style="height: 100%">

  <body style="height: 100%">

    <div style="height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">

      <div style="flex: 1; background-color: red;">1/3</div>
      <div style="flex: 1; background-color: blue;">2/3</div>
      <div style="flex: 1; background-color: black;">3/3</div>

    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What if I what the fourth div to be below the viewport?

Comment: then why don't you ask the full question? I can see what you are thinking, and you need to use JavaScript.

Comment: I know that if I were using a background image, I could simply set it's size to cover, and then put the other elements on top of the image. So isn't there an easier way than also using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care too much about old browsers, I'd suggest using flexboxes.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
}

div {
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    #1
  </div>
  <div>
    #2
  </div>
  <div>
    #3
  </div>
</header>
```

I've made the example over simplified, it will need correct browser prefixes for best compatibility.

Comment: For you code to work, you need to set height to 100% in HTML, BODY and HEADER tag. Also he said he need to make horizontal sections, not vertical ones. You property: flex: 0 0 33.33%; is correct in this case, but is not modular (so if later you need to have 25% size,  you need to modify the CSS). I guess is better to use "flex: 1", so all his brothers will have the same width size.

Comment: Agree with your point, but something like `flex: 1 1 auto` will not guarantee all 3 divs have the same size. It depends on what Suonpera wants. (I prefer the complete shorthand syntax because of IE not handling correctly partial ones). But definitively using flexboxes.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old thread, however, I didn't see a concrete solution.  To prevent the scrolling issue, I always add the following CSS code at the top of the page:

```
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

I also normally create a "reset.css" or "reset.scss" file that includes the above code.  For additional CSS reset coding, copy and paste code from this website:
https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

You can also Google "CSS reset" and you'll find this site typically as the 2nd or 3rd search result.

To reference your new "reset.css" or "reset.scss" file in your index.html, add the following code within your "head" tags.  I have mine in a "styles" folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/reset.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/reset.scss">
```